# Как избавиться от квадратных скобок при выводе словаря?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Как избавиться от квадратных скобок при выводе словаря? (На input: `a aa abC aa ac abc bcd a`. Выводит: `a [2]aa [2]abc [2]ac [1]bcd [1]`)

```
lst = [str(i) for i in input().split()]
d = dict()
cnt = 0
h = 0

for  i in lst:
    d[i] = []
    cnt = lst.count(lst[h])
    d[i].append(cnt)
    h +=1


for key in d:
    print(key, d[key])
```

Comment: print(key, *d[key], sep=' ')

Answer (score 2):

У вас значения словаря - это списки. Списки выводятся в квадратных скобках. Можно "развернуть" список с помощью знака `*`:

```
print(key, *d[key])
```

Comment: почему в этом случае не подойдёт `''.join(d[key])`?

Comment: @Violet ну можно и так. Питон свободный язык, много вариантов сделать одно и то же

Comment: Вопрос в другом, `join` не даёт нужного результата, я пробовал на приведенном в вопросе коде

Comment: @Violet А, ну потому что там числа, а не строки, а `join` для строк. Можно так: `''.join(map(str,d[key]))`